# How to Enabling the option to convert layer transparency to color transparency for ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api, publishing

i have a trouble for publishing map service with transparent color, but when i make analyze map document, there error "warnings",told me (Enabling the option to convert layer transparency to color transparency for ArcGIS Server).

[image: here the error]

Comment: please any one help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already fixed the problem as I see by the fact that the warning says it is "resolved". The way to do this is to right-click the warning and you are given the option to resolve the conflict right there.

You do NOT want to try to adjust this in the mxd project file (leave the transparency value that you have set for the layer). When you save the service, the description of the service will show transparency:0 for the layer but you will be able to see through it to the layers below.

Edit:
If you did try to modify the transparency, you should go back and set it the way you had it.

I had a similar problem and I fixed it by opening the mxd project that I used to create the service, setting transparency on the layer by right-clicking it in the Table of Contents and setting Transparency to 50% or so on the Display Tabl. Then I shared the service. When using the layer in my javascript map. I also had to set opacity on the layer so perhaps that may help.

```
var myLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("xxx.xxxxxxxx.org:6080/arcgis/rest/services/LAYER/F‌​older/…;, {"imageParameters": imageParameters, opacity: 0.45, format: "png32"}); imageParameters.format = "png32"; map.addLayer(myLayer);
```

[My Transparency Issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112669/layer-vs-color-transparency-with-arcgis-javascript-api)

Comment: thank you@jbchurchil, actually the problem is not showing transparent the layers in my application is still full fill color

Comment: Ok I will edit my answer and hopefully offer some good advice.